# Weird behavior in sculpting. SHIFT causes brush to shrink to 1 pixel

Tags: sculpting

So, I was sculpting away and everything was normal, I switched to photoshop and set up Wacom express keys for my cintiq. Now back in blender pressing shift won't smooth as it normally does (the brush continues to draw instead of smooth), and when I release shift, it immediately shrinks the cursor to 1 pixel...

I've completely removed the wacom drivers, I've updated to blender 2.78a and it is still happening, using just the mouse and keyboard. In user preferances it shows that it should be working as smooth.

Can anyone think of a reason SHIFT would cause the cursor to shrink to 1 pixel instead of modifying the stroke to cause smoothing, like it usually does?

[image]

Comment: OK, so it seems to be a problem with that specific blend file. Importing it to a new file, seems to work fine.